# What to pass for %c in printf() if we want to print nothing at that place?

Tags: c, printf

I am writing a code in which a certain character must be displayed based on some condition and nothing must be displayed (not even space) if that condition is not fulfilled.I am using `printf()` with `%c` conversion specifier.When I want to print nothing then I passed `'\0'` for `%c` but that is printing a space.What should I have to pass for my purpose?

Comment: If you want to print nothing, then do not call `printf` in that condition. Printing `\0` displays an unprintable character (it might look like a space, but it's not - it's a non-visible character code).

Comment: You should change the format specifier based on whether you have a character to print; failing that you could pass a string instead of a character using `%1s` as a format specifier, and then the empty string would be supported, but that would probably be less clear and possibly slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `%s` with an empty string for no character, e.g.:

```
printf("foo%sbar", condition ? "+" : "");
```

If the character is in a `char` variable then:

```
printf("foo%.1sbar", condition ? &ch : "");
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no value that can be passed for the argument corresponding to a `%c` specification to `printf` that results in no character being printed.

To not to print a character, you must not execute `printf` with a `%c` specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide your statement, for example if you have statement like this one:

```
printf(" %d  %c %s \n, par1, par2 par3);
```

you can divide it as follows:

```
printf("%d", par1);
if( a_condition_is_true) printf("%c", par2);
printf("%s\n", par3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII control codes, like BEL: `'\a'`. This will confuse users who may hear a spurious sound, and other coders who may not understand why the code tries to raise user's attention.

It is far better to write a condition with two distinct `printf()` statements. This solution makes code the most readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

to print a space (effectively printing nothing)  Suggest:

```
printf( "%c", ' ' );
```

-or-

```
putc( ' ', stdout );
```

-or-

```
putchar( ' ' );
```

-or-

```
fputc( ' ', stdout );
```

Or to literally print nothing, you can use the ANSI escape sequence:

```
printf( "/x2b[1C\n" );
```

Which will move the cursor right 1 space without printing anything